# is it possible to use SSL_connect for http?

Tags: c, http, https, openssl, code-reuse

Is it possible to use SSL_connect() and related API of OpenSSL, for "http" connections ALSO? My program reads the hostname from the command prompt in linux terminal as argument to command, and I don't want to write two different codes switching between "http" and "https" for fetching web-pages..... So just using SSL connection API functions, is there a way to connect to a web server on port 80 without encryption? For the sake of reusing same code simply.

Comment: Just use libcurl instead of trying to write your own http client.

Comment: I came across the answer below, I guess IMPOSSIBLE to reuse OpenSSL API functions with downgrading to unencrypted http requests...PITY!!! I think ONLY if use BIO APIs under OpenSSL, this is POSSIBLE...if I am wrong PLS comment! : 
**ANSWER :**
No, it's not possible to run HTTP and HTTPS on the same port.

When using HTTPS the connection uses the SSL/TLS protocol from the very start. There is no possibility for the client to start transmitting using plain HTTP.

The SSL/TLS standard doesn't provide for a way to drop back to HTTP if plaintext communication is detected on the port.

Comment: Use a BIO. Just use a standard socket BIO (or whatever) for HTTP. When you want to do TLS add an SSL BIO into the BIO chain.

Comment: @Matt Caswell, THANKS...that is a REAL comment! I completely agree..got it ...!